# How do I embed a pre-populated form in an email?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a link for a pre-populated form that I want to embed in an email.

How do I write a script to include the pre-populated form in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just provide a link to the prepopulated form in the email? [This thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/docs/xPQxt6Pl4Cg) suggests that you avoid embedding the form in email because not all clients support it. Also, I am unsure of how you would pre populate a form in an email because there are not any configuration options when you embed in email.